# The verify email link doesn't seem to work

Tags: laravel

After I got some help on stackoverflow on how to send a verify email link using Laravel 5.7 I got that working. But when I click the link it just shows me the login page. How can I solve that issue?

The link I received is: 
http://api.domain.com/api/email/verify/1?expires=1544631409&signature=314d837c49276ce212bdd94a383f35

(I removed half of the signature when posting on stackoverflow)
I do hope someone can help me with this issue.

Kind regards,
Kevin

Comment: Looks like the `Auth\VerificationController` has the `auth` middleware in its constructor `$this->middleware('auth');` by default. This might be why you are redirected to the login page.

Comment: I've started using Laravel today for the first time haha. Can you explain to me how to fix that issue? Edit: Just found VerificationController.php and removed the middleware auth line. Did not solve the issue.

Comment: You either have to log the user in or remove `$this->middleware('auth');` from `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/VerificationController.php`

Comment: Yeah sorry I was a bit too fast. I removed that line and it did not solve the problem

Comment: You have the correct configuration for your schema per the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification#verification-database

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/b59SURd.png 
This should be correct right?

Comment: Looks right. Is the user logged in when you send the verification email? You can start debugging by pulling in the `verify` method into the `VerificationController` https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/VerifiesEmails.php

Comment: The user is not logged in when they click on the verification mail. I want them to first verify their email and login afterwards. It's to login in the API I'm writing. So it's not really a login session but login with a JWToken.
Maybe this helps to clear it up a bit: https://i.imgur.com/zNSkrBu.png

Comment: It could also be my api.php file. I'm not really sure. But maybe this screenshot also helps.

https://i.imgur.com/Nbrf2nz.png

Comment: That won't work with the way its written by default. The user will need to be logged in or you'll need to modify the implementation. You'll notice the `verify` method uses `$request->user()` to get an instance of your user when performing the verification. If you want to protect your routes from users that have not verified an email address you can use `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified` in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185162/discussion-between-kevin-walter-and-adam).

Comment: `... got some help on stackoverflow on how to send a verify email link` - so how are you sending it? Laravel's auth stuff, including sending verify email links and logging in, works out of the box. So what have you changed, what was wrong first time around, and what have you done since?  What does your `laravel.log` show?

Comment: @adam After searching for a LONG time I finally found the problem (And it's more or less what you already suggested). In the auth.php I changed the default guard to web and now it works. For some mysterious reason. The api knows which guard to pick. But the web doesn't and goes back to the default which was the api guard..... So now I forced it to take the web guard. But I still would like to know why it doesn't take the web guard when it's specified....

Comment: @KevinWalter If you change the default guard to say `api` in your case, I think you need to specify the guard via the web so: `auth('web')->attempt($credentials)`